# How do I pass an angularJS value into a directive properly to be used in a method?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a directive to be used in the index.html with the following:

```
<choose-import data-file-type="FileValueIChoose"></choose-import>
```

my directive's function in js is as follows:

```
function chooseImport() {
    return {
        scope: {
            fileType: "@fileType"
        },
        restrict: "E",
        templateUrl: "/Static/Directives/ChooseImport.html"
    };
}
```

My directive's HTML is as follows:

```
<div style="margin-top: 20px" data-ng-controller="uploadcontroller as vm">
{{fileType}}
<input type="button" data-ng-click="vm.TestUpload({{fileType}})" />
</div>
```

Now this gives an error as it complains about the syntax. If I use

```
vm.testUpload('{{fileType}}')
```

It will just pass in a string of '{{fileType}}' instead of the actual value I want, in this case "FileValueIChoose".

How do I pass in the value so it can be used in the method's vm.TestUpload()?

Note: I just want to pass in a string value into the method properly without having a syntax error.

Comment: The correct `ng-click` syntax to use would be `ng-click="vm.TestUpload(fileType)"`. I would recommend setting the directive's controller in the directive definition rather than using `ng-controller`

Comment: @Phil Thanks. I can't believe I missed that.